# Taking multiple values against each key using for loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

```
student_marks = {'Raj':[20,30,40,48], 'Raja':[25,35,46,22]}
```

I want to write a code which would enable the user to take inputs in the form as outlined above. I have seen code snippets for taking in one value against each key but couldn't find one where they take in lists as values.

Comment: Alright. I will do it

Comment: "I want to write a code". But your asking us to write you code?

Comment: @BuddyBob, yeah i want to but i'm unable to and hence asking for help. Okay, now??

Comment: No worry @dubey, I am working on it. But please tell me how many names you want from input

Comment: The no of names would also be a user input @RishabhSemwal, Thanks Rishabh for helping out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i = 0
marks_list = []
name = list(map(str, input("Enter names: ").split()))
while i < len(name):
    marks = list(map(int, input("Enter " + name[i] + " marks: ").split()))
    marks_list.append(marks)
    i += 1

student_marks = {name[i]: marks_list[i] for i in range(len(name))}

print(student_marks)
```

Here is the answer which works.
Enter input like this.

```
Enter names: Raj Raja
Enter Raj marks: 20 30 40 48
Enter Raja marks: 25 35 46 22
```

Output:

```
{'Raj': [20, 30, 40, 48], 'Raja': [25, 35, 46, 22]}
```

Comment: I get a type error: it says list object not callable...... name =list(map.....)

Comment: what do you type in input

Comment: It is working fine in my pc

Comment: Make sure names are inputted in one line with space between them. Like I do in answer. Please read full answer for that

Comment: Sorry my bad, I had list defined as variable in one of my codes and that probably had things gone awry. It works fine when i tried it in a fresh notebook. Thanks man!!

Comment: You can asks question in this site and send me the link of question here in the comments. I will do my best to solve your problems

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232760/discussion-between-dubey-and-rishabh-semwal).

Comment: @RishabhSemwal Please note that comments on posts should only address the technical aspects of the question/answer, they are definitely not meant for conversations. SO is a Q/A site meant to contain useful information, not a forum.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want something like this

```
dic = {}
while True:
    student = input("enter student name : ")
    if student:
        mark = input("enter student mark split by ',' : ").split(",")
        dic.update({str(student): mark})
    else:
        break

print(dic)
```

Comment: while true takes the code into an infinite loop so i tried taking an input, ran a for loop, and i copied the rest of your code. It works fine, Thanks man!!